# Azure Search suggestions setup

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

I've created an instance of Azure Search and I'm trying to make use of the suggesters functionality but struggling to find any useful information on how to get started (poor and out of date documentation from Microsoft).

I would like to use a suggestion on the name field below.

[image]
The issue is that fields require unique names and I'm unable to edit existing fields. I'm a little unsure of how the suggester tab differs from basic.

Does anyone have any advice on how best to add suggesters to my index? I am all for deleting the index and starting again if I've missed something critical.

Comment: One of the most frustrating aspects of Azure is that so much of the documentation feels like an afterthought. - Interesting question though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really sorry you're disappointed by the documentation. We take it very seriously and will make sure to address your feedback. Feel free to make suggestions.

On the screen you provided, you should specify a name for the suggester. Once you do that, checkboxes will show up next to your field names. Using the check boxes you will enable the Suggestions API on selected fields.

Use the name of the suggester as a value for the *suggesterName* parameter when using the Suggestions API : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798936.aspx

Please find more details in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-search-how-to-add-suggestions-auto-complete-to-your-search-applications/) about suggestions in Azure Search. It describes a sample application with code attached.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I add a suggester name, the check boxes appear but I'm unable to check them (on existing fields). Should I be creating a new field in the index and duplicate the values?

Comment: I see. If these are fields of an existing index you won't be able to apply a suggester on them. Enabling the Suggestions API requires us to process your documents differently (for accurate and efficient matching). Once they are indexed, we don't reindex them automatically. You will need to do it yourself by recreating your index or creating a new field with correct configuration and reindexing its content.